# На что заменить PNativeInt при переносе из python4delphi в Delphi 2010?

Tags: python, delphi

На что можно заменить PNativeInt в Delphi 2010 ?

```
PyDict_Next:  function(mp : PPyObject; pos: PNativeInt; key, value: PPPyObject):integer; cdecl;
```

Answer (score 2):

Тип `NativeInt` был введён в первой Delphi с 64-разрядным компилятором (XE2), и он представляет собой `Int64` для  64-разрядной сборки, и `Integer` (Int32) для 32-разрядных приложений.

В D2009 только 32-разрядные, поэтом должен быть `PInteger`

**Edit** В комментах указали, что тип уже был объявлен в той версии Delphi. Может быть, указательного типа на него не было, тогда достаточно

```
 type  PNativeInt = ^NativeInt;
```

P.S. Кстати, [вот в этом клоне/ветке](https://github.com/tangentstorm/py4d/blob/master/PythonForDelphi/Components/Sources/Core/PythonEngine.pas) (как это называется?) ситуация разрулена так
(однако странно, что `CompilerVersion < 21`, ведь 21 версия - это D2010, по моему разумению должно быть 23 (XE2))

```
{$IFNDEF FPC}
   {$IF CompilerVersion < 21}
      NativeInt = integer;
      NativeUInt = Cardinal;
   {$IFEND}
   PNativeInt = ^NativeInt;
...
```

Comment: Спасибо дорогой человек!!! Помогло.

Comment: Собрал с PInteger, после чего установил компонент. Вроде пока работает.

Comment: @Машина времени Если там много мест с данным типом, стоит сделать определение типа,  подобно тому, как я привел.  И -  галочка слева помечает ответ как решение

Comment: @MBo, "Тип NativeInt был введён в первой Delphi с 64-разрядным компилятором (XE2)" - [вы ошибаетесь](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/System.NativeInt). Более того, он был даже в 2007й ЕМНИП, но там он был жёстко замаплен на Int64, что некорректно.

Comment: @Alekcvp  В чём именно ошибаюсь? В другой версии Delphi?

Comment: @Alekcvp Увидел, что ваша ссылка на 2010. Однако не так просто найти, когда введён тип. [Есть сводка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460037/) основных новых фич, но введение этого типа там не отмечено.